# Spinner image changes in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have two spinners in my activity.
Both with the same custom background image.
On selecting the value from 1st spinner the values of 2nd spinner changes.
But when that happens there comes the default radio button image of android on the 2nd spinner.
This problem persists in the android version 2.2.

Here are screenshots.

[image: The default state Image of Spinner]
The default state Image of Spinner

[image: On selecting a value from spinner 1]
On selecting a value from spinner 1

The down arrow image is the spinner.
As you see in the second screenshot the radio button how do I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved silly mistake by me

Only needed to change

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.city_arrays,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


use this code
```